# Parametrization of a path for line integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, line-integrals, parametrization

> Compute the integral $$\int\limits_{\alpha} z \,\mathrm{d}z$$ over the path $\alpha$ from $i+1$ to $-i$ to $1-i$.

I sketch this path and it's a incomplete triangle. We've never done any examples what to do and in which way. How I get the boundaries for the integral? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: "Over the path..." doesn't say much: **what path**?

Comment: The path **from $i+1$ to $-i$ to $1-i$**

Comment: Again, that doesn't say much: there are **infinite** paths between those two points. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. This is the exact task on my sheet: "... with $\alpha$ as a path from..."

Comment: Then they seem to mean that the solution does **not** depend on the chosen path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume straight line from $1+i$ to $-i$, and then straight line from $-i$ to $1-i$.

For the first straight path,
$$x=1-t, y=1-2t$$
where $t=0\to 1.$

The integral is
$$\int_{t=0}^{t=1} \left(x+iy\right)\left(dx+idy\right)=\int_0^1 \left(1-t+i(1-2t)\right)\left(-dt-2idt\right)$$
$$=-\int_0^1\left(1-t+i(1-2t)\right)(1+2i)dt$$
$$=-\int_0^1\left[(-1+3t)+i(3-4t)\right]dt$$
$$=-\left[-t+\frac{3t^2}{2}\right]_0^1-i\left[3t-2t^2\right]_0^1$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}-i$$

For the second straight path,
$$x=t, y=-i$$
The integral is
$$\int_{t=0}^{t=1}(x-i)dx$$
$$=\int_0^1(t-i)dt$$
$$=\left[\frac{t^2}{2}-it\right]_0^1$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}-i$$

So the total integral is
$$(-\frac{1}{2}-i)+(\frac{1}{2}-i)$$
$$=-2i$$

Comment: Thank you. How do you get the parametrizations?

Comment: Drawing a diagram and helped by geometry.

Comment: So, in fact that this is a triangle?

Comment: No. It is just two sides of a triangle.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That's what I mean. But how you get the x and y part?

Comment: You mean how I came up with $x=1-t$ and $y=1-2t$?

Comment: Exactly, this two things!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\;F(z)=\cfrac12z^2\;$ is a primitive to $\;z\;$ , and thus for **any two points** $\;z_0,\,z_1\in\Bbb C\;$ ,we have that the integral from $\;z_0\;$ to $\;z_1\;$ is

$$\int_{z_0}^{z_1}z\,dz=F(z_1)-F(z_0)$$

Comment: Okay, thank you! So in fact of your answer above I can't do more?

Comment: @jacmeird Just to evaluate both integrals: from point 1 to point 2, and from point 2 to point 3. I think the answer is $\;-2i\;$ ...